# How do you distinguish between a timeshare system, a VM, and a container?

Tags: containers, virtualization

A [time-share](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-sharing) system, a virtual machine and a container all seem very similar. How do you materially and meaningfully distinguish between them? What are the merits, benefits and drawbacks of each technology?